# Random values in Visual Basic express 2010 adding up to 100

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to write a piece of code in Visual Basic 2010 express which generates 4 different random values which add up to 100 and favors one of the values in terms of actual numeric value, I know how I'm going to make a certain value be favored in terms of value however I'm not sure about having all the random values add up to 100, could someone provide some raw or sudo code for me to work from please ?

Comment: Please add the code you have so far so we can work on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way is:

- Generate 4 random values (r1, r2, r3, r4) - you could put these in an array or in four variables.
- Calculate `100/(r1+r2+r3+r4)`
- Multiply each of your 4 values by this number

If you need integers, there is a chance that rounding will cause your numbers to add up to something not exactly 100. In that case, choose another random integer between 1..4, call this n, and add or subtract from r(n) so that the total adds up to exactly 100.

Comment: I don't quite understand, so I'll be declaring an array of 4 integers to begin with ? Then dividing them by 100 ? Which will leave me with 4 random values which have been downscaled. I don't quite understand how this will help me, would you like me to explain the scenario a bit more ?

Comment: Sou you need integers? This makes it a bit harder - you must round the values, which might bring you off 100. Use a 5th random value in the to decide, which of the values r1..r4 you adapt to hit exactly 100

Answer (score 2):

Generate 3 random numbers from 0 to your limit (100), but each time the random number is generated subtract it from your limit.  The 4th number will be the remaining value of limit and these 4 number will add up to 100.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim limit As Integer = 100
        Dim rand As New Random

        ' Generate three random numbers
        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            Dim newNumber = rand.Next(0, limit)

            ' Set your new limit by subtracting the random number
            limit = limit - newNumber
            Console.WriteLine(newNumber)
        Next
        ' The 4th number will be whatever is left in limit
        Console.WriteLine(limit)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: What if the first random number generated is 99?

Comment: It still would work...  You would end up having a new limit of 1, which means rand.Next would look like "rand.Next(0, 1)".  The maxValue is exclusive so 0 would be generated.  This would cause the following result:  99, 0, 0, 1.

Comment: I know your method works, but I wonder if 0 or lower numbers would appear a disproportionate number of times?  I mean that it seems "less random".

Comment: That would depend on the seed value which should be based on DateTime, so it's as "random" as it can be.